# jQuery selector - input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I'd like to enable the textbox when it is clicked. However, when I click the textbox, nothing happens. I believe it is a problem with the jQuery selector. Why isn't this working?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(':input').click(function() {
            $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
        });
    });
</script>
<input type="text" value="123" disabled="disabled" />
```

Note: I tried both $('input') and $(':input') to select the textfield. Neither worked.

Comment: Do you know if the function is being called? Try putting an alert statement in the function to see if it's being called in the first place.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Remove disabled attribute onClick of disabled form field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921161/remove-disabled-attribute-onclick-of-disabled-form-field). Long story short, disabled elements do not fire `click` events.

Comment: Just curious, can you explain the use case for such behavior?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A disabled input isn't going to fire events.  Try changing from disabled to readonly.

Comment: Keep in mind that this only works for type="text" and type="password"

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with the selector you're using, but rather because, since the `input` element is disabled, the events for the input will not fire - see: http://www.jsfiddle.net/DvZDh/

```
<input type="text" value="123" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="text" value="123" />
```

The code works on the second `input` element, but not the first. A simple solution would probably be to use CSS to simulate the disabled state instead.

Comment: Thank you for the link, it's very useful. That's a great website.