# ASP javascript radiobutton enable disable not included in postback ajax

Tags: asp.net, radio-button, postback

Here is the problem. I have a radiobutton group (two radiobuttons).

These guys are initialy disabled. When the user clicks a checkbox, I dynamically enable radiobuttons in javascript by setting `rbtn.disabled = false;` and doing the same for it's parent (span element) so it correctly works in IE.
The problem is that these dynamically enabled radiobuttons are not returned on postback (I see `rbtn.Checked == false` on serverside and `request.form` does not contain proper value).

Why is this happening? Is there another fix except for a workaround with hidden fields?

Expected answer decribes post-back policy, why/how decides which fields are included in postback and fix to this problem.

Comment: Hi 0xDEAD BEEF, just to make sure - are you using ASP.net? Or classic asp? As I'm not completely certain from your tags.

Answer (score 1):

Before doing the `submit`, remove the `disabled` attribute from the radio buttons like this:

```
document.getElementById("rbtnID").removeAttribute("disabled");
```

Note that `removeAttribute` can be buggy in IE, and IE also implements a second attribute for case sensitivity, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536696%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) article.

There is also `removeAttributeNode` which removes the entire attribute node, but it takes the `node` itself as the parameter instead of the name.

```
var disabledNode = element.getAttributeNode('disabled');
element.removeAttributeNode(disabledNode);
```

So give these a shot and let me know how they play out!

Answer (score 1):

I know the following code is not neat, but it gets the job done (if I understand the problem correctly). I copy/paste here the whole file contents to make it easier for you to play with it. Just create a web form named `WebForm1` and paste these;

in .aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function enable(sender) {
        if (sender.checked) {
            document.getElementById('<%= RadioButton1.ClientID %>').removeAttribute('disabled');
            document.getElementById('<%= RadioButton2.ClientID %>').removeAttribute('disabled');
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('<%= RadioButton1.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('<%= RadioButton2.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
        }
    }
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" onclick="enable(this)" />

    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Text="1" 
         Enabled="false" />
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" Text="2" 
         Enabled="false" />

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
        onclick="Button1_Click1" />

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

in .aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        static readonly string GROUP_NAME = "RadioButtonGroup";
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RadioButton1.GroupName = GROUP_NAME;
            RadioButton2.GroupName = GROUP_NAME;
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                if (CheckBox1.Checked)
                {
                    RadioButton1.Enabled = true;
                    RadioButton2.Enabled = true;
                    if (Request.Params[GROUP_NAME] == RadioButton1.ID)
                    {
                        RadioButton1.Checked = true;
                    }
                    else if (Request.Params[GROUP_NAME] == RadioButton2.ID)
                    {
                        RadioButton2.Checked = true;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.Params[GROUP_NAME] == RadioButton1.ID)
            {
                Label1.Text = "1 is selected";
                if (Request.Params[GROUP_NAME] == RadioButton2.ID)
                {
                    Label1.Text += "and 2 is selected";
                }
            }
            if (Request.Params[GROUP_NAME] == RadioButton2.ID)
            {
                Label1.Text = "2 is selected";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a chance to test this myself, but I'm guessing (if your using ASP.net), that your disabling the radio buttons via the ASP.net server-side code i.e via a server side control.

And then renabling them using javascript?

I think perhaps that the server-side still believes they are disabled - I'm not 100% why without digging futther (something in the page lifecycle somewhere).

Perahaps a quick solution would be instead of disabling the radio buttons via server-side, instead disable them in javascript when the page loads? i.e. doing the disabling and enabling in javscript.

Answer (score 0):

Before submitting the page set the `disabled` property of the radios buttons to `false`. In the code behind read the radio button value using `Request.Form["radioButtonName"]`. This will give you the value of the radio button which is checked.

Example:

Let say the radio button list name is `radioButton1` with 2  radio buttons. When it renders on the page the radio buttons will have the same name say `ctl0$radioButton1`. Anyways it depends on the nesting of your page. You can get this name using `radioButton.UniqueID`.

When the page is submitting through any action on the page execute the below javascript which will set the disabled property of the radio button to false.

```
document.getElementById("radioButton1ItemCliendId").disabled = false;

//If you want to check this radio button then
document.getElementById("radioButton1ItemCliendId").checked = true;
```

On the server side postback event handler you have to use `Request.Form[radioButton1.UniqueID]` to get this radio buttons value. It will give the radio buttons value which is checked.

Comment: This looks very similar to previous answer!

Comment: Similar in what sense? Have you mentioned you have to use `Request.From[radioButton.UniqueID]` to get the disabled radio buttons value after post back?

Comment: The solution is basically the same (to remove the disabled attribute). Reading the values serverside - the OP is already doing that (he mentions that in his post).

Comment: Just setting the `disabled` property to `false` is enough, removing the `attribute` is not required. Tested and tried in all browsers including IE.

Comment: Also OP did not metion what is he passing in `request.form` to get the value that is very important. You have to use `UniqueID` of the radio button server control to get its value after postback.