# Clicking a disabled input or button

Tags: javascript, jquery, disabled-control

Is it possible to click on a disabled button and provide some feedback to the user?

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="click" disabled>
```

and JavaScript:

```
$('input').mousedown(function(event) {
    alert('CLICKED');
});
```

The above code is not working for me; neither is this:

```
$('input').live('click', function () {
    alert('CLICKED');
});
```

Comment: I don't think the click event will be fired on a disabled control

Comment: all the events are removed for disabled controls

Comment: then why you disabled it

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is no way to capture a click on disabled elements. Your best bet is to react to a specific `class` on the element.

HTML Markup:

```
<input type="button" class="disabled" value="click" />
```

JavaScript code:

```
$('input').click(function (event) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
        alert('CLICKED, BUT DISABLED!!');
    } else {
        alert('Not disabled. =)');
    }
});
```

You could then use CSS styling to simulate a disabled look:

```
.disabled
{
    background-color: #DDD;
    color: #999;
}
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/puYxX/1/) demonstrating its use.

Answer (score 23):

Making the field `readonly` can help, because the click event will be fired. Though be aware of the [differences in behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730695/whats-the-difference-between-disabled-disabled-and-readonly-readonly-for-te).

```
<input type="button" value="click" readonly="readonly" />
```

Answer (score 19):

Put

```
input[disabled] {pointer-events:none}
```

in your CSS (it prevents some browsers from discarding clicks on disabled inputs altogether), and capture the click on a parent element.  It's a cleaner solution, IMHO, than putting a transparent overlay over the element to capture the click, and depending on circumstances may also be much easier than simply "simulating" the disabled state using CSS (since that won't prevent the input from being submitted, and also requires overriding the default browser 'disabled' style).

If you have multiple such buttons, you'll need a unique parent for each, in order to be able to distinguish which button was clicked, because with `pointer-events:none`, the click target is the button's parent rather than the button itself.  (Or you could test the click coordinates, I suppose...).

If you need to support older browsers, though, do check which ones support `pointer-events`:  http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events

Comment: works for me in FF - easiest and most compatible answer

Comment: That should be accepted answer, works on chrome too

Comment: works with a div wrapped around the disabled button

Answer (score 4):

You can't without a workaround, see: [jQuery detect click on disabled submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833854/jquery-detect-click-on-disabled-submit-button)

The browsers disable events on disabled elements.

Edited to add context from link:

The asker found this thread with an explanation of why the events aren't registering: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=186057

> Firefox, and perhaps other browsers, disable DOM events on form fields
>   that are disabled. Any event that starts at the disabled form field is
>   completely canceled and does not propagate up the DOM tree. Correct me
>   if I'm wrong, but if you click on the disabled button, the source of
>   the event is the disabled button and the click event is completely
>   wiped out. The browser literally doesn't know the button got clicked,
>   nor does it pass the click event on. It's as if you are clicking on a
>   black hole on the web page.

The workaround would be style the button to "look" disabled, while not actually being so.

Answer (score 2):

`disabled` elements will not allow the user to interact with them.

So: no, you can't put an `onclick` on a `disabled` button and expect it to fire.

Answer (score 0):

`<input id="idButton" type="button" value="click" disabled>`

```
$('#idButton').on('click', function() {
    // The button is disabled but this will be executed.
});
```

The above example works with JQuery for disabled buttons that need the event to be captured.

Comment: Why do you think this works?  Is it due to the ID?  Or because it's a button?  Or the value? This doesn't work at least on a text input.

Comment: To be honest Im not sure but I suspect it is the order JQuery associates the listener when loading the DOM or it most likely just disregards the disabled property when doing so.

Answer (score 0):

you can't click on disabled button, but can click on disabled link

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $txt = $('div.text');
  if($(this).attr('disabled')){
    $txt.html('CLICKED, BUT DISABLED!!');
  }else{
    $txt.html('Not disabled. =)');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">No action</div>
<input type="button" href="" class="btn" value="click" />
<input type="button" href="" class="btn" value="click disabled" disabled />
<a href="" class="btn">Click</a>
<a href="" class="btn" disabled>Click Disabled</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

What about wraping the button in some element and catching click on this element instead?

```
<span id="container">
    <input type="button" value="click" disabled>
</span>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#container").click(function(){
    alert("Element clicked!");
})
```

Comment: I like your answer, but unfortunately it doesnt work. I guess `disabled` blocks event propagation or something

Answer (score -3):

You should used disabled="disabled" and not just disabled.

```
$('input:disabled').val('disabled');
```

Comment: you can't click on any element with disabled="disabled" - that's the point of disabling it.