# Show alert message when clicking on disabled text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii

I want to check whether the textbox is disabled or not. If we try to click on the disabled textbox. It should show an alert message.

This is my model code :

```
var isDisabled = $("#Travellerpaymentinfo_cc_number").prop('disabled');
if(isDisabled==1)
{
    $("#Travellerpaymentinfo_cc_number").click(function(){
      alert("The textbox is clicked.");
    });
}
```

Comment: Well, i have no idea how this is related to php, but i think - i just think - you cant bind the `click` event onto a disabled element. Just a thought of mine.

Comment: Yeah, events are disabled on disabled elements.

Comment: There is no way to capture a click on disabled elements. Your best bet is to react to a specific class on the element. You can refer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109228/clicking-a-disabled-input-or-button . Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since disabled control elements can't have events bound to them, you'd need to bind an event to an ancestor element and make a check to see whether the target was the input.

You can then go on to check if it's disabled, and if so, show your alert:

```
$(document).on('click',function(e){
    if(e.target.id == "Travellerpaymentinfo_cc_number" && e.target.disabled){
        alert("The textbox is clicked.");
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ycrLB/)

Comment: The above code is not working for me.Is there any other way friends.

Comment: @QuestSasi it should work. What browser and did you use the code exactly like it is here?

Comment: @epascarello I have used the above code as is but it is not working. I am using YII framework. Will it affect ? I am using firefox latest version.

Comment: @QuestSasi Your right, it doesn't work in Firefox. Seems the event doesn't propagate from a disabled element. It's tempting to ask a question..

Comment: Check out this work-around: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3100395/1612146

Answer (score 2):

Events do not work on disabled elements, you can do this as a workaround

**HTML**

Add readOnly attribute

```
<textarea id="Travellerpaymentinfo_cc_number" class="disabled" readonly="true"></textarea>
```

**CSS**

Make it look disabled with css

```
.disabled{
    background:lightgrey;    
}
```

**jQuery**

You can put the if statement in the click event like this

```
$("#Travellerpaymentinfo_cc_number").click(function () {
    if (this.readOnly) {
        alert("The textbox is clicked.");
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/2kwKc/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have your conroll disabled, also the events which you can fire are disabled. One possible thing you can do is, that you set the textbox to readonly, so you can fire events if someone clicks it

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" readonly="true" />

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#textbox').click(function(){
        alert("not allowed");
    });
});
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
  if ($("#"+e.target.id).prop('disabled') && e.target.id=="Travellerpaymentinfo_cc_number"){
    alert("The textbox is clicked. ");
  }
});
```

`isDisabled` is only a Boolean(True or False)

Comment: Learn about truthy values `alert(true==1)`

Comment: first run above code and give comment

Comment: if u say wrong...just say where its wrong

Comment: Dude, `if (true)` and `if(true==true)` and if `(true==1)` produce the same result.

Comment: The problem is the fact that you can not click on a disabled input and receive a click event by a handler bound to that control.

Comment: After your edit: Still not going to work.  $(this) is the document, not the element.

Comment: thanks dude...just now i understand the problem