# jQuery click event on disabled input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trigger an event on a disabled `input`. I have tried the following code, nothing happened - there was no error, the even just didn't fire.

```
$(document).on('click', '.select-row', function(e){
    ...
});
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I think a disabled element cannot be clickable. Do you really need to apply this property?

Comment: Here is a good alternative  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109228/clicking-a-disabled-input-or-button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't fire any mouse event like click on a disabled HTML element. Alternative of this, is to wrap up the element in a span or div and perform the click event on those.

```
$("div").click(function (evt) {
  // do something
});​
```

One more alternate is to make the element `readonly` instead of `disabled`, but bear in mind that jQuery does not have a default `:readonly` selector.

Answer (score 2):

If it works for you, you may use `readonly` instead of `disabled`. Then you can use the click event with ease.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Ujwal_15/nfputckv/)

Answer (score 0):

We had today a problem like this, but we didn't wanted to change the HTML. So we used [mouseenter](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) event to achieve that

```
var doThingsOnClick = function() {
    // your click function here
};

$(document).on({
    'mouseenter': function () {
        $(this).removeAttr('disabled').bind('click', doThingsOnClick);
    },
    'mouseleave': function () {
        $(this).unbind('click', doThingsOnClick).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    },
}, '.select-row');
```

Answer (score 0):

This my solution

```
<div class="myInput"><input type="text" value="" class="class_input" disabled=""></div>
```

Jquery:

```
$("body").on("click", ".myInput", function(e) {
  if($(e.target).closest('.class_input').length > 0){
     console.log('Input clicked!')
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need to trigger, use `trigger()` function.

```
$('.select-row').trigger('click');
```