# Put information message that user cant continue ,if number of rows is not true

Tags: javascript, php

I have code

```
if($rowcount1 > 0){
        ?>
            <h3 class="text-muted"><u>DEPARTURE</u></h3>
            <h4><?php echo "$origin to $destination "?></h4>
                <table class="table table-hover">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>FLIGHT NO.</th>
                      <th>DEPART</th>
                      <th>ARRIVE</th>
                      <th>AIRPORT</th>
                      <th>DURATION</th>
                      <th>FLY ONLY</th>
                      <th>FLY + BAGGAGE</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                     <?php
                        foreach ($query as $flightr) {
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>".$flightr['id']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$flightr['depart']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$flightr['arrive']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$flightr['airport']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$flightr['duration']."</td>";
                            echo "<td> <label for=lbl7> <input type='radio' checked id='lbl7' name='flight[]' value='".$flightr['flyonly']."'> PHP ".number_format($flightr['flyonly'])."</label></td>";
                            echo "<td> <label for=lbl8> <input type='radio' checked id='lbl8' name='flight[]' value='".$flightr['flybaggage']."'> PHP ".number_format($flightr['flybaggage'])."</label></td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }
                     ?>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <hr>
                    <?php

                        }else{
                            echo " <div class='alert alert-info' role='alert'>
                                       No results found on <BIG class='text-muted'>Departure</BIG> pick another flight thank you.
                                    </div>
                            ";
                        }
        }
        }
    ?>
    <button type="button" name="forform" onclick="" class="hit">hit</button>
```

how to put info message that user cant continue (and they cant click the button to continue), if number of rows is not true. Via button onclick. begginer in js sorry. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `disabled` attribute of button based on rowCount

```
<button type="button" name="forform" onclick="" class="hit" 
       <?php echo ($rowcount1 > 0) ? '' : 'disabled'; ?>>hit</button>
```

Comment: much better then mine

Comment: it can still continue because i have a js script on my button class 'hit' maybe the js function is overriding it? how can i do it?

Comment: if button is disabled then on click script will not execute

Comment: my button has a class hit. my hit function in js have a location.href

Comment: Might be this will help you what you want to achieve on disabled button
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109228/clicking-a-disabled-input-or-button

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by put button in if else condition with disable attributes

```
if ($rowcount1 > 0) {
    ?>
    <h3 class="text-muted"><u>DEPARTURE</u></h3>
    <h4><?php echo "$origin to $destination " ?></h4>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>FLIGHT NO.</th>
                <th>DEPART</th>
                <th>ARRIVE</th>
                <th>AIRPORT</th>
                <th>DURATION</th>
                <th>FLY ONLY</th>
                <th>FLY + BAGGAGE</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    <?php
    foreach ($query as $flightr) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $flightr['id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $flightr['depart'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $flightr['arrive'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $flightr['airport'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $flightr['duration'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td> <label for=lbl7> <input type='radio' checked id='lbl7' name='flight[]' value='" . $flightr['flyonly'] . "'> PHP " . number_format($flightr['flyonly']) . "</label></td>";
        echo "<td> <label for=lbl8> <input type='radio' checked id='lbl8' name='flight[]' value='" . $flightr['flybaggage'] . "'> PHP " . number_format($flightr['flybaggage']) . "</label></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <button type="button" name="forform" onclick="" class="hit">hit</button>
    <?php
} else {
    echo " <div class='alert alert-info' role='alert'>
                                       No results found on <BIG class='text-muted'>Departure</BIG> pick another flight thank you.
                                    </div>
                            ";
    echo '<button type="button" name="forform" onclick="" class="hit" disable="disable">hit</button>';
}
?>
```