# Click function not working; is there a problem with the syntax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to display an alert in the screen upon clicking an ID that starts with `titleNotes` and another ID that starts with "contentNotes". my first attempt in using such selector is with the use of `.css("cursor", "pointer")` which is a success, so i tried implementing such selector in the click event, which doesn't work. is there something wrong within my syntax?

Here's my script:

````
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#changeIcon").click(function() {
        $(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-th fa-list");
        $("body").find("#gridContainerMain").toggleClass("grid-container-3 grid-container-1");
        $("body").find("#fillerColumnTop").toggleClass("grid-item-whole-column-filler-3-grid-container-state grid-item-whole-column-filler-1-grid-container-state");
    });
    $("[id^='titleNotes'],[id^='contentNotes']").css("cursor", "pointer");
    $("[id^='titleNotes'],[id^='contentNotes']").click(function() {
        alert("try"); //this is not alerting the user
    }); 
    $("[id^='deleteNotes']").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
        console.log(id);
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/deleteidentifier.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                id: id
            }
        })
        .done(function(response){
            if (JSON.parse(response)) {
                alert("Moved to deleted folder.");
                window.location.reload();
            }
            else {
                alert("Failed!");
            }
        });
    });
});
```
and here's the php code that contains the IDs in which the script would try to find

```
<?php
    include "db.php";
    $sql_display_notes = "SELECT * FROM notes WHERE user_id = '$account_id' AND archived_status = 'n' AND deleted_status = 'n'";
    $query_sql_display_notes = $conn->query($sql_display_notes);
    while ($result_query_sql_display_notes = $query_sql_display_notes->fetch_array()) {
        $note_record = $result_query_sql_display_notes["note_record"];
        $note_type = $result_query_sql_display_notes["note_type"];
        $note_title = $result_query_sql_display_notes["note_title"];
        $date_created = $result_query_sql_display_notes["date_created"];
        $note_id = $result_query_sql_display_notes["note_id"]
        ?>
            <div class="grid-padding-all" id="<?php echo $note_id; ?>">
                <button type="button" id="deleteNotes<?php echo $note_id; ?>" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <input name="note_title" id="titleNotes<?php echo $note_id; ?>" class="note_display" disabled="" value="<?php echo $note_title ?>" title="created on <?php echo $date_created; ?>. Note type: <?php echo $note_type; ?>">
                </input>
                <textarea name="note_record" id="contentNotes<?php echo $note_id; ?>" class="note_display" disabled=""title="created on <?php echo $date_created; ?>. Note type: <?php echo $note_type; ?>"><?php echo $note_record; ?></textarea>
            </div>
        <?php
    }
?>
````

Comment: There is no element with `id="changeIcon"` in your code

Comment: The element with id `changeIcon` seems to be missing.

Comment: Use class instead of id for duplicate nodes

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, always, talking about client-side code debugging should be regarded with the output of the browser's console. In other words, does your browser invoke any error messages?

Comment: Using disabled inputs... `There is no way to capture a click on disabled elements`... check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109228/clicking-a-disabled-input-or-button/16109366#answer-16109366).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clicking a disabled input or button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109228/clicking-a-disabled-input-or-button)

Comment: @Pupil the changeIcon is used on another webpage. this is irrelevant on this one