# How to add alert on disabled asp.net drop-down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I have a drop-down like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cboJPRem" class="jprem" runat="server">
     <asp:ListItem Value="None" Selected="True" Text="None"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="1day" Text="1 day"></asp:ListItem> 
</asp:DropDownList>
```

This drop-down gets disabled and enabled based on value of field 'check A'. If check A is 'T', drop-down will be enabled, if check A is 'F' drop-down will be disabled.

My requirement is to give an alert message(To enable this drop down, change the value of 'check A') when user clicks on disabled drop-down.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#cboJPRem").change(function(){
                if($("#cboJPRem:selected").attr("id") == "cboXyz"){
                    alert("To enable this drop down, change the value of 'check A'");
                }
            });

        });
```

Above code is my attempt to add alert but it is not working. 
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Yes there is a way, and it's called jQuery.

Comment: disabled elements can't raise events.

Comment: Might be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109228/clicking-a-disabled-input-or-button

Answer (score 1):

Check comments on code:)

```
$("#cboJPRem").on('change', function() {

    //this will help you to retrive the selected value. 
    var yourVal = $('option:selected', this).attr("id"); 

    //confirm if value is retrived properly
    console.log(yourVal);

    if(yourVal == "cboXyz") {
        //do your stuff
    }
});
```