# How can I make a disabled button do something when clicked? (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

So I have this piece of code:

```
var delete_disabled = (parseInt(row.attr("data-state"), 10) === serverVars.obligationStateNotStarted) ? '' : 'disabled="disabled"';
        newHtml += "<button class=\"delete small\"" + delete_disabled + " title=\"" + labelDelete + "\"><i class=\"icon-trash\"></i></button>";
```

It checks if a certain criteria is met and if it is then it disables the button however once the button is disabled I would like something still to happen when I click on it? I've tried everything I can think of and was hoping for some suggestions. 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833854/jquery-detect-click-on-disabled-submit-button This could help you.

Comment: Play with its layout to give the impression it's disabled, but instead of disabling it, just attach a different handler for the click event.

Comment: Don't disable it, make it look like it is disabled (from an user perspective, gray text and background, etc...) and handle its state with a variable or something.

Comment: That's not disabling a button, that's destroying it by replacing/reparsing it's HTML to have a completly new and different button with a (not even standard) disabled keyboard. Use attribute `disabled="disabled"`

Comment: disable a button and pretend it still does something while disabled is a big "no no" IMHO.

Comment: Once you disable button no event is identified with respect to that button. you can deal with css to make it look like disable without using disabled attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively to actually firing an event when clicking the disabled button, you can add a dummy element in front of a disabled button and add a listener, associated with the disabled state, on that element. For example,

http://jsfiddle.net/FN45M/

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
/*this click listener could also be added as part of the disableButton function.*/
    $(document).on('click', '.click-div', function () {
        console.log('clicked');
        alert('clicked');
    });

    disableButton($('button'));
    //enableButton($('button'));

});

function disableButton($el){
    var wrapper = $el.wrap("<div class='wrapper'>").parent();
    wrapper.css({"display":"inline","position":"relative"});
    var divClick = $("<div class='click-div'>");
    divClick.css({"position":"absolute",
                  "top":0,
                  "height":"100%",
                  "width":"100%"
                 });
    wrapper.append(divClick);

    /*divClick.on('click', function () {
        console.log('clicked');
        alert('clicked');
    });*/
}

function enableButton($el){
    $el.next(".click-div").remove();
    $el.unwrap("<div class='wrapper'>");
    $el.prop("disabled",false);
}
```

**html**

```
<button disabled>test</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following code

JQuery:

```
$("button#disabled, button#enabled").click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('id') === 'disabled'){
        alert('disabled');
        // do your suff here for disabled button
    } else {
        alert('enabled');
        // do your suff here for enabled button
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<button id="disabled" style="color: graytext;"><i>disabled</button>
<button id="enabled">enabled</button>
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/sZ2vT/2/)