# If a disabled input button is clicked, display message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input button, which when it is disabled, and someone tries to click it, needs to display an alert.

How is it possible to display a javascript message despite being disabled?

Tried this with no luck:

`<input type="submit" onclick="alert('click')" value="Disabled Input Button" disabled/>`

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7834293/3751213, however you may use `mousedown` event...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833854/jquery-detect-click-on-disabled-submit-button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<span  onclick="alert('This input is disabled')">
    <input type="submit" value="Disabled Input Button" disabled/>
</span>
```

Wrapping it with another tag that has the on click function works.

Answer (score 4):

Use `onmousedown` instead of `onclick`, which is only fired when it is 'allowed' to. Some browsers, particularly Chrome, appear to disable all DOM events when a form element is disabled. While I think this is out of spec, you can use the following workaround:

Instead of using the `disabled` attribute, use CSS `pointer-events` to achieve a similar effect, [illustrated here](http://jsfiddle.net/w9eQc/):

```
button.disabled {
    pointer-events:none;    
}
```

And then just use `<button class="disabled">` instead of `<button disabled>`.

Comment: what if the user navigate through the button using tab key and press enter ?

Comment: Thanks, Just found this also works: `<span  onclick="alert('This input is disabled')"><input type="submit" value="Disabled Input Button" disabled/></span>`

Comment: Yeah I found some conflicting reports on browser adoption of the first solution. Added a simple workaround which is neater than using sparse markup as in the other suggestions.

Comment: I have removed this as the answer due to it not working on Chrome.