# changing ''checked' attribute of a checkbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp

right now when it first loads the html page, my checkbox was created in this way:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="CBOX1" name="CBOX1" onclick="onCBOX(this)" disabled/>
```

in a function in on the same html:

```
boolean checked = true;
document.theForm.elements['CBOX1'].checked = true;
```

For some reason, the checked box value is not checked when the function is called later on the page. Is it because when i first created the checkbox, i created it without a 'checked' attribute? And then when i assign it a value, the element doesnt seem to include the checked attribute anymore as when i check on the source of the page. its still the same...

```
<input type="checkbox" id="CBOX1" name="CBOX1" onclick="onCBOX(this)" disabled/>
```

For simplicity sake, i know for sure that there were changes made to other attributes of this element using AJAX, but i am at a loss to WHY the checked attribute is not carried over... What's the alternative?

Comment: Is `checked` a variable? If yes, where is it defined? What value does it have? You have to assign a boolean value to `document.theForm.elements['CBOX1'].checked`.

Comment: Where does `checked` come from in that first line of JavaScript? The `checked` **property** of a checkbox is supposed to be a boolean, true or false, value.

Comment: Is `checked` a defined boolean var that is true or false ?

Comment: Lol. 3 ppl with the same question

Comment: Either use `"checked"` or `true`.

Comment: When you check the source of the page does it really say `<input type="checkbox" id="<%="CBOX1"%>" name="<%="CBOX1"%>" onclick="onCBOX(this)" disabled/>`. ie the HTML in the browser has those attributes with `<%=...%>` in them? If so then this is your problem...

Comment: @João: No. The `checked` property is always boolean, setting it to `"checked"` would only lead to a type cast to `true`

Comment: Or it might be that your checkbox is disabled. I don't know if you might be having problems with changing the state of a disabled control...

Comment: @bouncingHippo: There are no `click` events fired on disabled form elements: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1680625/1048572

Comment: @Bergi: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.checkbox.html

Comment: @João: That spec is for the `checked` *attribute*, and that has no `true` value… The DOM *property* is `boolean`

Comment: @Chris, i have no problem changing the state of the disabled. again, i have a input checkbox without a 'checked' attribute, and i want to use javascript function to modify the DOM property of checked but viewing the source shows that the input checkbox doesnt have a 'checked' attribute

Comment: @bouncingHippo: that was the least of the concerns. Try addressing questions such as whether you have `<%=%>` in the HTML of your page. The HTML source not having the attribute doesn't mean anything (except that it is not set).

Comment: no i dont have the <%=%> in my pages

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check a checkbox with jQuery or JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: hey @bouncingHippo I can feel your pain. You are asking a specific question and you get all the wrong answer. Did you manage to find a way to set the attribute in the html, not just the property of the element in the memory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the checkbox:

```
document.theForm.elements['CBOX1'].checked = true;
document.theForm.elements['CBOX1'].checked = "checked";
```

Uncheck the checkbox:

```
document.theForm.elements['CBOX1'].checked = false;
```

If you want it unchecked on load then don't touch it, by default it is unchecked.

Moreover, no click events will be registered if you use the **disabled** attribute on your input field.

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kgdvm/) for an example.

**EDIT**

If clickability is not the issue then just do what I already pointed out. Here is a **full** working example.

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <input id="tar" type="checkbox" disabled />
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="callFunc(this)" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function callFunc(elem){
    document.getElementById("tar").checked = elem.checked;
   }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i need it unchecked when the page loads ie via <input checkbox ....> and then after user plays with it, the function will ADD a 'checked' attribute to it..

Comment: @bouncingHippo - If you want the user to interact with your input element then remove the disabled attribute.

Comment: clickability is not the issue here, when i first create the checkbox <input checkbox..> it doesnt have a 'checked' attribute. later on, i use document.theForm....checked=true doesnt seem to work as checking the page source shows that <input checbox...> is still MISSING the checked attribute even after the function is called on it...

Comment: @bouncingHippo - You must be doing it wrong. See edit for a clear working example of the previously stated attribute settings in action. Debug your code better before making false assumptions or developing could take a LONG time. **MOREOVER**, checking the page source only shows what the state of the page was *when it loaded*.

Comment: youre right i fixed the problem using your advice. thanks and please upvote the problem, appreciate it

Comment: @bouncingHippo - I cannot change the vote unless the question is edited (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/178816). However, I will not reverse the vote unless the question is made unique - it is currently an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/426258/1026459 in that all it is asking for is to change the checked value of a checkbox through javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it to `true` instead:

```
document.theForm.elements['CBOX1'].checked = true;
```

Comment: i cannot set it to true first as our client wants it to be checked=false when the page first loads, and depending on incoming data, it will checked=true....

Comment: Then set the value `true` based on the incoming data. Not sure what your issue is here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, not tested anyway.

```
document.theForm.elements['CBOX1'].checked = true;
```

Comment: i cannot set it to true first as our client wants it to be checked=false when the page first loads, and depending on incoming data, it will checked=true....

Comment: Then change `true` to `false`. i.e. `document.theForm.elements['CBOX1'].checked = false;`. Hope this solves ur problem cos i'm not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: in other words <input checkbox...id=... checked='false'> ?