# Using click event while button is disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check on clicks while the button is disabled is this possible? Or is there any other way to this?

HTML:

```
<form id="form">
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$("#form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
    $("#submit").on("click", function () {
        alert("Bla");
    });
});
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hjYeR/1/

Comment: Is this what you need? http://jsfiddle.net/hjYeR/2/

Comment: Can you run whatever code you want to run before you preventDefault and return false?

Comment: Do not give a submit button in a form an ID or name of "submit", it will mask the form's submit method (i.e. form.submit will reference the button, not the method).

Comment: Thanks @karthikr That almost works I just need it to work at the first time and not the second click

Comment: maybe can help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921161/remove-disabled-attribute-onclick-of-disabled-form-field

Comment: Then why don'y you start off enabled, then disable the button on first click?

Comment: Well it just continues for me that way http://jsfiddle.net/hjYeR/5/

Comment: How about separating the 2 - http://jsfiddle.net/hjYeR/6/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using `preventDefault()`, there is no need to use `return false`.

However, any code after `return` statement in a function, won't execute.

Also there is no need to attach an event inside another event, write them separately:

```
$("#form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

$("#submit").on("click", function () {
    alert("Bla");
});
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hjYeR/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

After you `return false;` the rest of your function will not run.  You can bind your click event before returning false and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

`return` statements are the end point in the function, the codes will not proceed ahead of that.

What you can do is simply remove the `click` event handler from within the `submit` handler itself.

```
$("#form").submit(function (e) {

    return false; //e.preventDefault(); is not needed when used return false;

});

$("#submit").on("click", function () {
    alert("Bla");
});
```