# how to select limit number of options in multiple select plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, multiple-select

I am new in jquery.

I am using multiple select plugin jquery.

I want that the user can't select more than 3 options.

Here I have also disabled the selectall option.

Here is my code:

```
<select multiple id='testbox'>
  <option value='1'>First Option</option>
  <option value='2'>Second Option</option>
  <option value='3'>Third Option</option>
  <option value='4'>Fourth Option</option>
  <option value='5'>Fifth Option</option>
</select>
```

Jquery code:

```
$("select").multipleSelect({
    selectAll: false
 });
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT :**

There working [jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/o2swcxwc/1/) with multi-select plugin

```
var limit = 3;

var $multiSel = $("select").multipleSelect({
placeholder: "Here is the placeholder",
width: 200,
filter: true,
selectAll: false,
onClick: function(view) {
    var $checkboxes = $multiSel.next().find("input[type='checkbox']").not(":checked");
    var selectedLen = $multiSel.multipleSelect('getSelects').length;
    if (selectedLen >= limit) {
       $checkboxes.prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
       $checkboxes.prop("disabled", false);
    }
 }
});
```

Comment: This will not work if you select multiple items together using select. click on first element and then press shift and click on last element.

Comment: Edited with multiple-select plugin, is that better ?

Comment: thanks @EA-Lille that's what i am looking for!! thanks buddy

Comment: is it possible @EA-Lille if user clicks on 4 th checkbox it shows me alert message you can't select more . i waiting for your reply

Comment: You can't detect a click on disabled element. See this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/924731/6703798 .The only solution you have is to use CSS to simulate disabled and then you will be able a click on the fake disabled input. Like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16109366/6703798

Answer (score 0):

add `change` event for select and check for length of selected options

```js
  $("select").change(function () {
      if($("select option:selected").length > 3) {
          // you can disable rest of the things here
      }
  });
```

Comment: this is multiple select not multiselect

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
if($("select").multipleSelect("getSelects").length > 3)
{
   alert('Not allowed');
}
```